# Dart Redstone: How to use interceptors declared in different packages?

Tags: dart, redstone.dart

Interceptors work when I declare them in same package, but when I declare them in different package, they are not being registered and never being called.

How can I use interceptors declared in different packages?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using a single library with parts to have multiple groups, you can do it like this. You create a library (in `/lib`) containing all the groups. For example: `library rest_api`

Then, in the main file where you start redstone:

```
app.redstoneSetUp([#rest_api]);
```

Make sure you import the library first. The analyzer will most likely give you a warning for unused import, but you can ignore it by adding

```
// ignore: unused_import
```

before the line or at the end of the line that produces the warning.